# SP2-0640: Not connected

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle12c

I have 2 oracle db (ORCL and ORCL24) and I can't connect to ORCL database

[image]
«Выполняется» = Started

[image]

my listener.ora

```
 SID_LIST_LISTENER01 =   (SID_LIST =
     (SID_DESC =
       (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCL24)
       (ORACLE_HOME = G:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
       (SID_NAME = ORCL24)
     )   )

 SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
     (SID_DESC =
       (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
       (ORACLE_HOME = G:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
       (PROGRAM = extproc)
       (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:G:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")

 )
 (SID_DESC =
   (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCL)
   (ORACLE_HOME = G:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
   (SID_NAME = ORCL)
 )   )

LISTENER01 =   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PC)(PORT = 1526))   )


 LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
     )
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
     )   )
```

> ADR_BASE_LISTENER01 = G:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\log
>
> ADR_BASE_LISTENER = G:\app\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\log

Comment: `sqlplus /nolog` starts SQL\*Plus without a database connection.

Comment: as @William pointed out you need a connection to a schema. You can connect by using `sqlplus / as sysdba` or such as `sqlplus hr/pwdHr@yourDB` or `sqlplus /nolog` and then `conn hr/pwdHr@yourDB`.

Comment: Try `sqlplus / as sysdba` and then `startup`

Comment: SQL>
C:\Users\ASUS>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Dec 26 14:56:54 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.
SQL> startup
ORA-01012: not logged on
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Comment: @AndreiYakubets is %ORACLE_SID% parameter set properly? And look for the current file permissions where ORACLE_HOME stands.